# Malformed AJAX request? Where's the issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, model-view-controller

Here's my AJAX call:

```
var dataString = "{existingProject:'"+ $("#existingProject").val() + "',newProjName:'" + $("#newProjName").val()+"'}";
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "manageProjects.html",
        data: dataString,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.status + " " + msg.responseText);
            $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.status + " " + errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
```

..and here is the method signature in my Spring MVC Controller I expect to handle the request:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/manageProjects",produces="application/json",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public StatusResponse manageProjects(
        @RequestParam("existingProject") String existingProj,
        @RequestParam("newProjName") String newProj,
        HttpSession session){
```

I've been tinkering with this ajax call all day and I'm just not seeing the issue.  I've tried using load with a data argument, post, and I've tried without setting contentType and dataType and with it.

The responseText in the error message is telling me that the call is not syntactically correct....but there's no clue as to why...

I'm missing something stupid.  Thanks for any insight...

Comment: shouldn't dataType be "json"?

Comment: apologies.  typo on my part.  It's "json" in the code that's failing.  Fixed in the OP.

Comment: have you tried passing the parameters like this?
"existingProject="+ $("#existingProject").val() + "&newProjName=" + $("#newProjName").val()

... same result?

Comment: yeah same result.  It's worth mentioning these values are mutually exclusive.  One will always be "".  Is the problem that val() isn't returning "" but null and I'm therefore failing to meet the MVC signature for required arguments?

Comment: It could be the problem, you may want to try ensure avoid send nulls and see what happens

Comment: Used a below suggestion to JSON.stringify() the input data.  Result doesn't have null but shows up in the JSON as "".  What's weird is in the controller method I'm now getting in but both terms are null, despite not being null in the javascript dataString.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used tamper data plugin in firefox to check the data send by jquery. The payload was:

> POSTDATA=message=test+message

I applied the modification given by JayC on my JQuery request and it works. The details:

The modification given by JayC:

```
var dataString = JSON.stringify({
existingProject: $("#existingProject").val(),
newProjName: $("#newProjName").val()
});
```

My request:

> ```
>       function post(dest) {
>             var dataString = JSON.stringify({ message: 'test message'});
>             jQuery.ajax({
>                 type: "POST",
>                 url: ndest,
>                 crossDomain: true,
>                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>                 dataType: "json",
>                 data: dataString,
>                 success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {                       
>                 },
>                 error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
>                     handleError(response, textStatus, errorThrown);
>                 }
>             });
>         };
> ```

The Spring mvc controller part which handle the request:

```
@RequestMapping(value="myapp/{id}", method={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void setNote(@PathVariable("id") String user,  @RequestBody MyModel content) {
```

Now the payload is :

> POSTDATA={"message":"test message"}

Some hints:

- Use tamper data or any other sniffer to check payload of your request
- I see that you haven't @RequestBody in you method parameters. Maybe your json can't be parsed because you ask for nothing. Try do add `@RequestBody MyClass content`. MyClass should have correct corresponding getter and setter and a empty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid JSON.

Just do

```
var dataString = JSON.stringify({
    existingProject: $("#existingProject").val(),
    newProjName: $("#newProjName").val()
});
```

That'd work on most browsers.  In older browsers, you'd have to include a definition like on http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-json-serialization/   Note the definition there allows you to use a previously defined (native) version if it exists.

```
var JSON = JSON || {};  
// implement JSON.stringify serialization
JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function (obj) {
    var t = typeof (obj);
    if (t != "object" || obj === null) {
        // simple data type
        if (t == "string") obj = '"'+obj+'"';
        return String(obj);
    }
    else {
        // recurse array or object
        var n, v, json = [], arr = (obj && obj.constructor == Array);
        for (n in obj) {
            v = obj[n]; t = typeof(v);
            if (t == "string") v = '"'+v+'"';
            else if (t == "object" && v !== null) v = JSON.stringify(v);
            json.push((arr ? "" : '"' + n + '":') + String(v));
        }
        return (arr ? "[" : "{") + String(json) + (arr ? "]" : "}");
    }
};
```

Comment: Took your suggestion.  Used JSON.stringify and got he output data string that looks like this:

"{"existingProject":"default","newProjName":""}"

Same end result:  "request from client was syntactically incorrect"

When I change the MVC signature to make the methods required=false, I can get into the method but the arguments are null (despite being not null in the dataString I just described)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just putting your data in an object and setting that as the $.ajax data option?

it doesn't have to be stringified.

```
var data= {"existingProject" : $("#existingProject").val(), "newProjName" : $("#newProjName").val()};

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "manageProjects.html",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.status + " " + msg.responseText);
            $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.status + " " + errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, no change.  As described above I get: "HttpStatus 400 request from client was syntactically incorrect".  When I change the MVC signature to make the methods required=false, I can get into the method but the arguments are null (despite being not null in the dataString I just described)

Comment: hmm, is that the response you get from every browser?  if you look at the request in firebug, does it show the data properly?

Comment: Attempted other poster's suggestion and moved to a simple Object as posted above.  Firebug shows:

dataString  Object { existingProject="test" newProjName="" }

Result is still the same :-/

Comment: try taking off the dataType and contentType options.  i never use them for posting json back and forth with ajax.  

Firebug is showing dataString Object { existingProject="test" newProjName="" } as what's being posted? that is... odd.